# Bind camera button to Google Camera

Tags: sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z2

I have just installed Google Camera on my Sony Z2 device and i would love to fully move to it from default xperia camera app but the only thing which stops me from this is a camera button which is binded to the default app.

I have stopped / disabled the default app in Apps settings and now, after holding that button, my device vibrates for half a second and nothing happens. I assume i need to somehow change it's binding or set Google Camera to the default app but i have no idea how to do that and i can't find anything about it on the internet. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: nope, it's not. Actually i should ask if such thing is possible without a root

Comment: Unlikely without root.